# Reformatting a (disclosed and relevant) product advertisement

Tags: discussion

https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/98773/35312

That answer actually has relevant explanations (why do/don't certain oils behave so and so), and at the same time is advertising a product (in honesty, apparently).

Formatting is terrible, this should be edited.

Are there special aspects to consider when doing that to that kind of answer (which contains a statement by a manufacturer)?

Answer (score 3):

First a reminder: it’s ok to point to or mention a manufacturer or product, even if it’s the poster’s own. As long as a few conditions are fulfilled, as outlined in [this help center entry.](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/help/promotion)

In short: if the answer is actually an answer, not a promotion, and focuses on solving the problem, and discloses the poster’s relationship to the commercial website/service/whatever, it’s fine to mention and link to the other site for additional information.

We also have lots of users that preface their posts with a statement about their professional background or expertise (“I have worked as a cook for 15 years...”), which the community usually accepts as such and doesn’t edit out.

In this particular case, the (now removed) first paragraph could be seen both ways - emphasizing the knowledge of the poster, but with a somewhat „spammy“ touch.

Considering that

- the rest of the post is an answer as per the site’s rules,
- and the first bit was not necessary,

I simply decided to remove the questionable part instead of deleting the whole post as spam. The spam flags were justified nevertheless.

For the general formatting part, the same rules apply as always: If you can edit a post to make it easier to read, do so and thank you for your time.